# malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion Error

Tags: c++

I am coding in c++ and in the middle of a while loop I am getting this error

"malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
"

when I try to do

```
tempFilePath = tempFilePath + "/";
```

I've declared tempFilePath before the while loop and am confused what could be throwing this error.  Any ideas?

Comment: That code itself is fine, assuming it's a `std::string`. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You have corrupted the memory at some point before this. It is impossible to guess where and how.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I can't post too much due to my school's policy about assignments.  It is a std::string, that I'm trying to store into a struct that holds a string, file size and time that I'm then passing into a vector of these structs.

Comment: You said that you declared your variable but to use its value you must also initialize it.

Comment: Smells like ub, if your code is not massive you might be able to just eyeball it, otherwise you can run your code under something like valgrind to find the error.

Comment: @Vivick Op said in a comment it's an `std::string`, so it doesn't matter if the op explicitly gives it some initial value or not.